# Debugging PHP Unit without IDE/xdebug

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

How do you debug your PHPUnit tests without an IDE or xdebug? The fact that PHPUnit buffers all output seems to mean that I must use a debugger or IDE OR use [`$this->expectOutputString`](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.output) + `print_r()` (or whatever) and bunch of comments (since exepcts assertions get evaluated last, so I've had to comment out all my (failing) assertions).

What's the best practice here?

Comment: I dont know the best practice, but I always use error_log() to debugg, when using a notepad

Comment: Any decent PHP IDE has PHPUnit / debugging support. Why would you go back to ugly print_r or var_dump?

Comment: Because I'm teaching students. Our college has tradition of teaching using as bare tools as possible in the beginning and then letting students discover tools.

Answer (score 0):

IMO XDebug + IDE is almost always the best way to debug tests. However if you want to use good old fashion method with printing on the screen just use stderr output instead stdout.

For example:

```
fprintf(STDERR, "Some label\n");
fprintf(STDERR, "Array dump: %s\n", var_export($someArray, true));
```

Cheers!

Comment: You can also simply ECHO if you are running a console application.